# Edit menu for words in a view in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I show the edit menu for each word that is in each cell in the UITableview? 
The picture below is an example of what I want to do. I want to be able to select a word from the label viewed in each cell, and show the edit menu for that word.

[image]

Comment: By default edit menu will appear , have you disable user interaction anywhere

Comment: @Vinodh no I have all user interactions enabled

Answer (score -1):

You need to put some code inside tableview delegate.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //fetch the content of label ex: "cell.labelName.text"
  //Then put it on text box and allow editing ex:   

  textBox1.text=cell.labelName.text
  textBox1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

}
```